# Save Process Object Information for use after its exit

Tags: c#, listview, c#-4.0, process

On my C# Widows form, I want to make use of the Process object information even after its exit, but I am getting the exception ***“System process has exited, so the requested information is not available”***.

What I tried thus far is to save it as a var and tag it with my ListView item, but it still throws the same exception.

```
//ListView Parameters (omitted redundant ones)
Process currentProcess = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(processStringID);
newListViewItem.Tag = currentProcess;
listView.Items.Add(newListViewItem);
```

I have an event of selected index changed, so when the user clicks on the ListView Item, it should show information about the process that was tagged with the item even if it has already exited.

```
private void listView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

            Process processItem = (Process)listView.SelectedItems[0].Tag;

            //Sample of getting process information (Error happens here)
            MessageBox.Show(processItem.Name + processItem.VersionInfo);

            } 

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Tldr; I need a way to save the entire Process object so I can get it's information later even if the process has exited. I am open to ideas as to how this can be implemented. Please assist me, as I am unable to think of any solution with my current understanding on programming.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx),

To store data:

```
Session["process"] = processItem;
```

To pull data from session:

```
var process = (Process)Session["process"]; // Don't forget to cast back to it's original type
```

Data is available even if you navigate to other pages unless you manually remove it.

**Update:**

Since question is not clear at first.

Create a global variable using static classes

```
public static class GlobalVar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Global variable that is constant.
    /// </summary>
    public const string GlobalString = "Important Text";

    /// <summary>
    /// Static value protected by access routine.
    /// </summary>
    static int _globalValue;

    /// <summary>
    /// Access routine for global variable.
    /// </summary>
    public static int GlobalValue
    {
    get
    {
        return _globalValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _globalValue = value;
    }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Global static field.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool GlobalBoolean;
}
```

See this post : http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable

Comment: Session? To clarify, my program is a C# Windows Form program, not a web application. Sorry if I had not made myself clear earlier.